# AppDomains vs. a robust server

Tags: c#, appdomain

after doing some research it seems that AppDomains are not really a tool for building a hosting server. From my understanding, the hosting server will still crash if there is an unhandled exception in a created AppDomain (if the exception is thrown from a thread in the created AppDomain). So in that case if the hosting server hosts a service which leaks exceptions this will bring down the default AppDomain as well.

So I guess from a server architecture point-of-view there is nothing better than creating child processes and monitoring them.

Is that correct or am I missing something with AppDomains?

thanks,
Christoph

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can control the threads created in the other AppDomain, you can also handle exceptions by using catch-all blocks in the thread main method.

Other than that, as long as you use the default host, I believe that your assumption is correct. However, if you host the runtime yourself, you can also handle unhandled exceptions.

From a [forum post on the topic](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/clr/thread/a508c1a0-3c65-45a9-8c89-d809faf1ca0b):

> Well, it is possible.  You'd have to
>   create your own CLR host.  That starts
>   with ICorBindToRuntimeEx().  You get
>   to have full control of AppDomains
>   that throw exceptions.  And it's being
>   used by MSFT software like ASP.NET and
>   SQL Server 2005.  When you write a
>   service, you are working with the
>   default CLR host implementation and it
>   terminates the process when any
>   unhandled exception is raised,
>   regardless of what AppDomain caused
>   the exception.
>
> Problem is, hosts like ASP.NET and SQL
>   server have a very well defined code
>   execution path.  In a web server,
>   managed code runs because of a page
>   request.  In a dbase server, it runs
>   because of a query.  When something
>   bad happens, they have the luxury of
>   simply aborting everything that the
>   request started (killing the
>   AppDomain) and returning a "sorry,
>   couldn't do it" status back to the
>   client.  You might have seen it,
>   crashing the forums server on the old
>   web site was pretty trivial but didn't
>   stop it from serving other requests. 
>   Not actually 100% sure about that.
>
> Your service implementation is
>   probably not nearly as clean.  I can't
>   tell, you didn't say anything about
>   it.  It general, there's a problem
>   with aborting a thread.  You always
>   have to abort a thread when there's an
>   unhandled exception.  A service
>   typically has one thread, started by
>   the OnStart() method.  Aborting it
>   kills the server until somebody stops
>   and starts it again.
>
> You can definitely make it more
>   resilient than that, you could start a
>   "master" thread that launches child
>   threads in response to external events
>   that makes your service do its job. 
>   Having a child thread terminated
>   because of an unhandled exception  is
>   something you could possibly recover
>   from.  But then, if you make that next
>   step, why not have the child thread
>   catch an exception and pass it back to
>   the master thread so it can make an
>   intelligent decision about what to do
>   next.
>
> The cold hard fact of the default CLR
>   host is: if you are not willing to
>   deal with failure, it is not going to
>   do the job for you.  And it shouldn't,
>   the .NET 1.x behavior to threads that
>   died with exceptions was a major
>   mistake that got corrected in .NET
>   2.0.
>
> You know what to do: handle failure. 
>   Or write you own host.  Or accept that
>   things could be beyond your control
>   and log a good error message so you
>   can tell your customer what to do. 
>   I'd strongly recommend the latter.